# Filter and order with base R is not working

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a table (as data.frame) which looks like this one:

```
     Var1            Var2 Freq
364    NI           taq  100
363    BB           taq   47
323    AA           ret   46
361    99           taq   33
360    88           taq   69
138    77           esc   111
358    66           taq   26
357    55           taq   23
356    44           taq   20
355    33           taq   143
354    22           taq   105
314   1212          ret   66
352    11           taq   114
```

I want to remove "NI" from Var1 and order Freq from highest to lowest. Theoretically it could be done with

```
(df <- df[!df$Var1="NI" & order(df$Freq, decreasing=TRUE),])
```

But I get this:

```
    Var1           Var2 Freq
363    BB           taq   47
323    AA           ret   46
361    99           taq   33
360    88           taq   69
138    77           esc  111
358    66           taq   26
357    55           taq   23
356    44           taq   20
355    33           taq  143
354    22           taq  105
314   1212          ret   66
352    11           taq  114
```

NI is removed but Freq is not ordered as expected. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance

PS: I'm looking for a base R solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can first order the rows by `Freq`, and then filter out rows which `Var1 != "NI"`,since the descending order will not be affected by filtering.

In that case, your code can be written in a compact manner (no need two steps), i.e.,

```
dfout <- subset(df[order(df$Freq,decreasing = TRUE),],Var1!="NI")
```

such that

```
> dfout
    Var1 Var2 Freq
355   33  taq  143
352   11  taq  114
138   77  esc  111
354   22  taq  105
360   88  taq   69
314 1212  ret   66
363   BB  taq   47
323   AA  ret   46
361   99  taq   33
358   66  taq   26
357   55  taq   23
356   44  taq   20
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = c("NI", "BB", "AA", "99", "88", "77", "66", 
"55", "44", "33", "22", "1212", "11"), Var2 = c("taq", "taq", 
"ret", "taq", "taq", "esc", "taq", "taq", "taq", "taq", "taq", 
"ret", "taq"), Freq = c(100L, 47L, 46L, 33L, 69L, 111L, 26L, 
23L, 20L, 143L, 105L, 66L, 114L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("364", 
"363", "323", "361", "360", "138", "358", "357", "356", "355", 
"354", "314", "352"))
```

Comment: I was looking for a one step solution. Thank you! Anyway I'm still curious why (df <- df[!df$Var1="NI" & order(df$Freq, decreasing=TRUE),]) doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera `df$Var1 != "NI"` gives logical values, i.e., `TRUE` or `FALSE`, while `order()` gives you numerical values. When you have `df$Var1 != "NI" & order(df$Freq, decreasing=TRUE)`, you will get logical values, which omits orders of rows

Comment: @TomasIsCoding Thank you. I was missing completely that little but big mistake.

Answer (score 5):

We can `filter` the rows first and then do the `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     filter(Var1 != "NI") %>%
      arrange(desc(Freq))
```

---

In `base R`, `subset` the rows first and then do `order` based on the 'Freq'

```
df1 <- subset(df, Var1 != "NI")
df1[order(df1$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Comment: I know but I'm looking for a base R solution.

Answer (score 3):

you should do it in 2 step :

```
df = df[-(df$var1=="NI"),]
> df
   var1 var2 freq
3    BB  taq   47
4    AA  ret   46
5    99  taq   33
6    88  taq   69
7    77  esc  111
8    66  taq   26
9    55  taq   23
10   44  taq   20
11   33  taq  143
12   22  taq  105
13 1212  ret   66
14   11  taq  114
> df[order(df$freq, decreasing = T),]
   var1 var2 freq
11   33  taq  143
14   11  taq  114
7    77  esc  111
12   22  taq  105
6    88  taq   69
13 1212  ret   66
3    BB  taq   47
4    AA  ret   46
5    99  taq   33
8    66  taq   26
9    55  taq   23
10   44  taq   20
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the problem here except for your code not to be written properly :

```
df[df$Var1 != "NI" & order(df$Freq, decreasing=TRUE),]
```